# Why is the Z-transform so important in digital filters analysis and design?

Tags: z-transform, digital-filters

Please elaborate on why this mathematical transform can help analyzing as well as designing any type of digital filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Z Transform is to discrete-time (digital) signals precisely the same role that the Laplace Transform is to continuous-time (analog) signals.

Linear Time-Invariant (LTI) Systems (a.k.a. "filters"), are made up of signal-processing elements that fall into 3 fundamental classes:

1. adders (devices that add two signals).
2. scalers (devices that scale a signal by a constant).
3. "reactive" elements (devices that are able to discriminate w.r.t. frequency).

Element classes 1. and 2. are essentially the same for analog or digital filters.  The are sometimes called *"memoryless"* devices or elements.

For an analog filter (or "analog LTI system"), those reactive elements would be capacitors or inductors.  They integrate ($s^{-1}$) one signal to become another.  That turns a sine signal into a cosine signal or shifts the phase by $\pm$ 90°.

$$\cos(\Omega t) = \sin(\Omega t + \tfrac{\pi}{2})$$

For digital filters, the reactive elements are delay elements.  A unit delay (a delay of exactly one sample period $T$) will delay any signal, including a sinusoid, by 1 sample or $T$ units of time ($z^{-1}$).  That shifts the phase by an amount that is dependent on frequency

$$\sin(\Omega (t-T) ) = \sin(\Omega t - \Omega T)$$

or

$$\sin(\omega (n-1) ) = \sin(\omega n - \omega )$$

Any LTI system that acts as a *"filter"*, a device to filter out some frequency components and leave others, **must** have reactive elements (or *"non-memoryless"* elements or components having memory) in order to discriminate one frequency from another.  And such a filter will shift phase which will normally be different for different frequencies.  But a memoryless LTI system (which is just a scaler) will not discriminate between frequencies nor will shift phase, except for possibly by 180°, which is just a polarity reversal or scaling by a negative constant.